# Can't connect to a python socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcpclient, stm32h7

I am trying to send a string from STM32H750B-DK with TCP and receive and print it in python. Here is C code for TCP server:

```
/*
 * tcpserver.c
 *
 *  Created on: Apr 20, 2022
 *      Author: controllerstech.com
 */


#include "lwip/opt.h"

#include "lwip/api.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"

#include "tcpserver.h"
#include "string.h"
static struct netconn *conn, *newconn;
static struct netbuf *buf;
static ip_addr_t *addr;
static unsigned short port;
char msg[100];
char smsg[200];

char b[10] = {'0'};


/**** Send RESPONSE every time the client sends some data ******/
static void tcp_thread(void *arg)
{
    err_t err, accept_err, recv_error;

    /* Create a new connection identifier. */
    conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);

    if (conn!=NULL)
    {
        /* Bind connection to the port number 7. */
        err = netconn_bind(conn, IP_ADDR_ANY, 146);

        if (err == ERR_OK)
        {
            /* Tell connection to go into listening mode. */
            netconn_listen(conn);

            while (1)
            {
                /* Grab new connection. */
                accept_err = netconn_accept(conn, &newconn);

                /* Process the new connection. */
                if (accept_err == ERR_OK)
                {

                    /* receive the data from the client */
                    while (netconn_recv(newconn, &buf) == ERR_OK)
                    {
                        /* Extrct the address and port in case they are required */
                        addr = netbuf_fromaddr(buf);  // get the address of the client
                        port = netbuf_fromport(buf);  // get the Port of the client

                        /* If there is some data remaining to be sent, the following process will continue */
                        do
                        {

                            strncpy (msg, buf->p->payload, buf->p->len);   // get the message from the client
                            if (msg[0]==103){
                                b[0] = '1';
                            }
                            else{
                                b[0] = 'h';
                            }


                            // Or modify the message received, so that we can send it back to the client
                            int len = sprintf (smsg, "\"%s\" was sent by the Server\n", b);

                            netconn_write(newconn, smsg, len, NETCONN_COPY);  // send the message back to the client
                            memset (msg, '\0', 100);  // clear the buffer
                        }
                        while (netbuf_next(buf) >0);

                        netbuf_delete(buf);
                    }

                    /* Close connection and discard connection identifier. */
                    netconn_close(newconn);
                    netconn_delete(newconn);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            netconn_delete(conn);
        }
    }
}




void tcpserver_init(void)
{
  sys_thread_new("tcp_thread", tcp_thread, NULL, DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE,osPriorityNormal);
}
```

And here is python code for TCP client I am using:

```
import socket

SERVER_IP = "0.0.0.0"
SERVER_PORT = 146

# Create a socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(1)

print("Server listening on", SERVER_IP, "port", SERVER_PORT)

while True:
    client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connection from:", client_address)

    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if data:
        received_variable = int(data.decode())
        print("Received variable:", received_variable)

    client_socket.close()
```

When IP address is set to 0.0.0.0 it should listen on all available network interfaces so the program works, in console I get the message "Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 146", but can't get the connection. When I set the IP to 169.254.211.100 (IP address of my STM32) I get this error:

```
line 43, in <module>
    server_socket.bind((SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT))
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Otherwise I tried receiving the string in hercules and had no trouble connecting and receiving the string so I don-t understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: If you use socket.bind in Python too, you are creating a second tcp server. You have to use socket.connect. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445310/how-to-make-correct-tcp-request-using-python

Comment: socket.listen + socket.accept creates a TCP server, not a TCP client. So you are basically have implement two server which wait for some client to connect - but no client. Use socket.connect instead with the IP and port of STM32 as destination. socket.bind is usually not needed for the client at all since a local IP address and port for the connection will be picked automatically when connecting.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that. It works fine now.